# vb.net multidimensional array - Invalid attempt to read when no data is present

Tags: arrays, vb.net, multidimensional-array

here is the algorithm of my code:

```
for each stop time
for each arraysbu
for each funishop data
check if process description = dept name
check if stop time description = stop time description 
totallabor = totallabor + total labor in every furnishop data
totaloverhead = totaloverhead + total overhead in every furnishop data
end if
end if
end for each
end for each
```

My error is:

> **Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.**

Code:

```
Dim dept As New List(Of String)
Dim comm As New SqlCommand(sql, con)
'sql
Dim sqlcostcenterShofloor = "SELECT funishop.CostCentre, Process.ProcessDescription, funishop.LaborCost, funishop.OverheadCost, stoptime.Description FROM funishop INNER JOIN CostCentre ON funishop.CostCentre = CostCentre.CostCentreCode INNER JOIN WebfunishopLogin ON CostCentre.CostCentreCode = WebfunishopLogin.MachineCode INNER JOIN Process ON Process.ProcessCode = WebfunishopLogin.Process INNER JOIN stoptime ON stoptime.stoptimeCode = funishop.Action where funishop.Started >= '" & startdate & "' and funishop.Ended <= '" & enddate & "' ORDER BY stoptime.Description ASC"
'costcenter of funishop
Dim ccsfcomm As New SqlCommand(sqlcostcenterShofloor, con)
Dim ccsfreader As SqlDataReader
Dim processDesc As String
Dim stoptimeDesc As String

con.Open()
ccsfreader = ccsfcomm.ExecuteReader
ccsfreader.Read()
Dim totalLaborcost As Long
Dim totalOverhead As Long
If ccsfreader.HasRows Then
    'foreach(stoptime)
    For Each dtime As String In downt
        'for each dept
        For Each b As String In arraysbu
            'for each funishop
            Do
                If processDesc = b Then
                    If dtime = stoptimeDesc Then
                        totalLaborcost = totalLaborcost + ccsfreader.GetValue(2)
                        totaloverhead = totaloverhead + ccsfreader.GetValue(3)
                    End If
                End If
            Loop While ccsfreader.Read()
            cmblaborcost.Items.Add("jh23")
        Next
    Next
End If

con.Close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `Do` loop that reads every record in the data reader, but you have that inside nested `For Each` loops, which means that you're going to try to run that `Do` loop again after the data reader has already been exhausted.  Either only run that `Do` loop once or else use a data adapter to populate a `DataTable` so that you can access the data multiple times.

By the way, why call `Read` and then test `HasRows`?  Get rid of that first `Read` call and change your loop to `Do While...Loop` instead of `Do...Loop While` and your code will not throw that exception, but it still won't really make sense.

Comment: yes, Actually that is one of my prediction. but what will be the best solution to do? jmcilhinney

Comment: You can only read the result set of a data reader once.  If you need three nested loops then the loop that reads from the data reader must be on the outside.  In that case, get rid of the first call to `Read`, don't bother testing `HasRows` and use a `While` or `Do While...Loop` loop.  If you want to put the other `For Each` loops on the outside then don't use a data reader; use a data adapter to populate a `DataTable` and then use a third `For Each` loop.